# Using SQLite in main.dart from seperate file?

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I've followed this easy example from the flutter documentation. However, this is wrote in a separate file (db_test.db). I'm aiming to convert data into a ListView at some point. So, how would I use CRUD operations like retrieving data in my main.dart? I could add this to my main.dart file but I'd like to keep it clean and separate.

[Official Flutter tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite)

My db.dart file

```dart
void main () async {
  final database = openDatabase(

    join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'to_do.db'),
    onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute("CREATE TABLE tasks(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, created TEXT, INTEGER is_complete)");
    },
    version: 1,
  );

  Future<void> insertTask (Task task) async {
    final Database db = await database;

    await db.insert(
      'tasks',
      task.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace
    );
  }

  Future<List<Task>> tasks () async {
    final Database db = await database;

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('tasks');

    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Task(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        title: maps[i]['title'],
        created: maps[i]['created'],
        isComplete: maps[i]['is_complete']
      );
    });
  }

  Future<void> updateTask(Task task) async {
    // Get a reference to the database.
    final db = await database;

    // Update the given Dog.
    await db.update(
      'tasks',
      task.toMap(),
      // Ensure that the Dog has a matching id.
      where: "id = ?",
      // Pass the Dog's id as a whereArg to prevent SQL injection.
      whereArgs: [task.id],
    );
  }

  Future<void> deleteTask(int id) async {
    // Get a reference to the database.
    final db = await database;

    // Remove the Dog from the database.
    await db.delete(
      'tasks',
      // Use a `where` clause to delete a specific dog.
      where: "id = ?",
      // Pass the Dog's id as a whereArg to prevent SQL injection.
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you have defined the whole thing inside a `main` method, particularly considering this isn't in your `main.dart` file?

Comment: Hmm.. I'll be honest, I didn't even realize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new file containing Class with static members to help. Static members ensure that only one instance of database is created in your whole app.

```dart
class DatabaseHelper {
  static Database _database;

  ///Returns db instance if already opened
  ///else call the initDatabase
  static Future<Database> getDBConnector() async {
    if (_database != null) {
      return _database;
    }

    return await _initDatabase();
  }

  ///Open DB Connection, returns a Database instance.
  ///
  static Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    _database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), "my_path.db"),

      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        //on create
      },
      version: 1,
    );

    return _database;
  }

  //put your CRUD in static function
  static Future<void> insertTask (Task task) async {
    final Database db = await getDBConnector();

    await db.insert(
      'tasks',
      task.toMap(),
      conflictAlgorithm: ConflictAlgorithm.replace
    );
  }

  //the same with edit, delete
}
```

Then in your other file (like main.dart) you can just call it like this:

```dart
import "./databaseHelper.dart";
void caller() async{
  //create task

  //insert
  await DatabaseHelper.insertTask(task);
}
```

Make sure the caller is asynchronous.

Comment: This is called the "Singleton Pattern", and it has its pros and cons.